# Determine the next time a group of people are not busy based on events in apex?

Tags: apex, soql, user, javascript-remoting, event

I am looking to create a 'find next available time' button in my VF page that will take a group of people and do a remote call to my controller.

From the controller I want to get all the people's Ids, then determine the next time they are all available for a half hour chunk of time starting from the date and time the button was pushed.

The only way I am seeing how to do it is to loop through and query all events and event relations for the time frame if RelationId or OwnerId is in the set of user Ids passed from the button, and if anything is returned, try the next time slot. This obviously runs into the 100 query limit very easily...

But I am having trouble figuring out how else I might determine this and wondering if anyone here might have a viable approach to doing this.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you using Classic? In classic you can view a multi-user calendar that can show you what you are trying to program. So far Salesforce is still working on getting these kind of feature working in Lightning. If you want to vote on this you can go to this link: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DtJIAA0

Comment: We don't want to be limited to classic. But I need a way to do this in Apex. Another method I am trying is query all events in a month starting from today and just loop through them checking dates seeing if a half hour spot is open. I'm not sure if a better option exists.

Comment: Is a month the largest amount of time you can search or can you extend your search to the next three months, six months, or even the rest of the year? Because then you could create a list of Id's for all the people and do only one event list that you would have to break up into maps.

Comment: I could do any amount of time really, but I would just need to be careful because I could run into thousands events in just one month... Thus making the loop through of their dates costly.

Comment: Have you thought about using a batch class to compile a list of dates and times on the people's records that show when they are free for a half and hour and then you could query that information. It would not be as instantaneous or on-demand but it could be another possible solution.

Comment: That is better in the fact that I can just query that custom object, get next free time and boom, done. The downside is it isn't exactly accurate information at the click of a button :(. If people add new events or delete some right before checking for next available time those batch job results could be out of date. We could have it run very frequently, though...

Comment: Hmm maybe you could invoke a visual workflow every time a event is added, updated, or deleted so that it could go through the logic of creating the list of available dates and times for each user. That way you don't have to rely scheduled apex to make sure everything is up to date. And the visual workflow would be invoked as part of a trigger.